# Fancybox not opening onclick

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have my HTML like this:

```
<a class="addclubpop dispn" href="http://www.badmintonbuddy.com/RenderAddClub?id=<%=item.ClubID %>"></a>
                <a class="addclub" href="#"><img src="../../Content/Add.png" alt="Add to Profile" /></a>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".addclubpop").fancybox({padding:0,margin:0,autoDimensions:'true'});
$('.addclub').click(function () {
        playHere();
    });
});

function playHere() {
    if (readCookie("userlogged") == 0) {  //user not logged in
        //do something
    } else {        
        $(".addclubpop").click();
    }
}
```

The fancybox opens based on the logic of whether the user is signed in(from playHere function). The problem is that the fancybox opens only for the first time and any subsequent calls through playHere never opens the fancybox dialog. 
Any clue?

Comment: does it work if you remove the if/else statement ?   
function playHere() {
        $(".addclubpop").click();    
}

Comment: Are you sure the $(".addclubpop").click(); can work ? try to put it out of playHere() to see if it opens correctly.

Comment: Is the `click()` being triggered at all? Perhaps `readCookie("userlogged") == 0` on your second and third attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Change

$(".addclubpop").click();

to

$(".addclubpop").trigger('click');

Comment: still this is not working and I guess its not the issue with the syntax as its working for the first time.